# Error: Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code after installing Xcode10 beta 5?

Tags: swift, xcode, code-signing, xcode10

Briefly since downloading and installing Xcode 10 beta 5 I have not been able to get any Provisional Profiles to work. In fact, my application fails immediately with the following error message.

**Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code.**

It appears there’s a disconnect with provisioning profiles and certificates within Xcode.

Interestingly, when I switch on the Automatically manage signing option Xcode generates certificates. However my developer Provisional Profiles can't seem to find certificates. I have updated to the latest beta versions for Mac OS, iOS, and of course Xcode.

Honestly, I have tried manually creating certificates as well as profiles with no luck. I have been trying to find a solution since downloading the beta version a few days ago.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback and or suggestions for possible solutions.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try to delete all your developer certificates from Keychain Access first, then use the Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details -> Download All approach to successfully re-sign your code once again @Dalek

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sharkes Monken. However, after trying every possible solution including removal of all beta software I discovered a fix. In sum the error was a result of a folder that I created named (resource). 

I simply removed it from my project and create new folders with my desired content. Note that I gave each folder a different name. Honestly, I’m still not sure why the folder was causing issues? 

Presently, I am running apps in the simulator as well as my iPhone X without any issues.

Comment: Yeah that’s how pretty weird Xcode projects can get. Honestly if it works out, well it’s a relief rather than looking into common errors and yet trying all possible solutions but doesn’t work.

Comment: I’m facing the same problem and none of the common workarounds helped me. Xcode says `code object is not signed at all`, but isn’t generous enough to tell me which file is affected.

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully this will help someone. I updated from Xcode 9 -> Xcode 10 beta 6 and received the non-zero exit code error. My fix was to go to Product -> Clean Build Folder.

After doing this all the errors went away and I was able to run my project.